# My question incorrectly marked as duplicate

Tags: discussion, support, closed-questions, reopen-request

recently I asked a question here [WiFi keeps reconnecting when ICS is active on Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/1631343/wifi-keeps-reconnecting-when-ics-is-active-on-windows-10) and its been marked as a dupe by mistake
cause even though it has a lot of similarity to [USB WiFi Adapter Disconnects Every Few Minutes](https://superuser.com/questions/1467323/usb-wifi-adapter-disconnects-every-few-minutes) it's not the same at all

In my question, I have a problem with ICS which is Internet Connection Sharing and that's not mentioned in that question at all

Comment: "The network is disconnected due to a policy disabling auto connect on this interface." the error message is the same in both cases.

Comment: @DavidPostill Yes but this is mainly caused by ICS for me for that person might have been caused by something else since I have updated drivers so it's not that there can be multiple causes since it doesn't specify what caused it

Comment: @poqdavid - It’s a duplicate due to the solution.  Does the answers to the duplicate resolve your problem?  Have you tried those solutions?  If you have then edit your question and indicate that’s the case.  Just saying it’s not a duplicate isn’t enough to reopen it. ICS doesn’t really change the question that much.  You have not edited your question which means it’s ineligible to be reopened

Answer (score 2):

Your question being closed and marked a duplicate does not mean your question wasn't answered, it means that the correct answer is found at the indicated location. Your question will continue to exist on the site pointing people who find it to the linked question with the answers, which is the correct thing to do.

Comment: This existence will generate upvotes far more than if it was answered explicitly, we don’t want duplicate answers, makes it harder to find them. SE search is horrible….

Comment: @ramhound, it sure is. I actually back out of SE and use the Google site search function because it is so terrible.